# Making a facial expression involving both eyes looking towards the nose

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Her eyes are normal without any defects. But, she tried to roll her eyes' pupils into either the left or right corners of the eyes **on purpose** as showed in the picture.

[image]

Do we say "**she is squinting her eyes**"?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, she is intentionally "crossing her eyes" or "looking cross-eyed". The boy is rolling his eyes upward.

Comment: "cross-eyed: having one or both eyes looking towards the nose" (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cross-eyed), but what if both pupils go outward, away from the nose and towards the temples? and what if one pupil goes towards the nose & the other goes towards the temple? (look at this picture: https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/cross-eyed-young-man-23649254.jpg)

Comment: Is that even physically possible? It's certainly so unusual that there isn't an ordinary word for it; I would describe it as 'his eyes looking in different directions'.

Comment: @Tom that picture shows [*one eye on the pot and the other up the chimney*](http://folksongcollector.com/drummer.html). Also [**cockeyed**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cockeyed).

Comment: @Tom: That second picture is ["walleyed."](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=31626)

Comment: Colloquially, I'd say it's most common, when referring to the boy, to just say he's "rolling his eyes". "Upward" is assumed.

Comment: There's another related word "cockeyed".  I don't know if other English speakers use it, but it's common here in the UK to describe someone who has one or both eyes out of alignment, not necessarily the same as being cross-eyed.

Comment: An additional word relating to what @Tom said above - that can sometimes happen with a Lazy Eye https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strabismus, I have a form of this where if I focus, both of my eyes look normal, but if I 'unfocus', my right eye drifts to the right.  If someone permanently has this condition, they usually only see out of one eye, or at the very least have poor depth perception.

Comment: @JRE - that's not wall-eyed. If you mean the guy, that nothing more than 'looking upwards' or rolling his eyes. Wall-eyed is the opposite of cross-eyed, eyes pointing outwards, away from the nose, towards the 'walls' on either side. I'd definitely say she 'has a squint' - though I imagine that's a BrE usage as slang outside of medical terminology. Squinting would be either cross-eyed or narrowing to avoid bright light, but 'having a squint' is definitely cross-eyed.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. The picture of a wall-eyed person is not the boy next to the girl in the above picture. If you follow Tom's second link in the first comment, it shows a person who is definitely wall-eyed. Just to describe it in words, wall-eyed means that both eyes are looking *away* from the nose. Towards the walls, in fact.

Comment: @Tom If the left eye goes towards the temple and the right eye goes towards the nose, that's called "looking to the left."

Comment: @gonefishin'again.:  The "walleyed" picture is in the link in a comment from Tom, not in the posted pictures in the questions os the answers.

Comment: @KateBunting I've heard the term 'boss-eyed' to describe eyes looking apart from each other.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to Jack's answer: apparently "squint" in medical terms does indeed mean a medical condition where someone's eyes look like that all the time, but I don't think that's very common in ordinary English.

"Squinting" is usually the act of narrowing your eyes, for example when you are trying to read something with tiny writing
[image]

or because you're a cowboy, looking tough and intimidating. Or maybe it's just very bright.
[image]

Anyway, even then we wouldn't really say that these people are "squinting their eyes", we'd just say "they're squinting". It would be a bit like saying "smiling their mouth" (which is not correct).

Comment: Edited because I can actually remembering reading someone "has a squint" to mean they had some defect with their eyes. Honestly, I've never known what that exactly meant until I looked it up.

Comment: Thank you. "smiling their mouth" is an example to demonstrate the way we would not speak like that, right?

Comment: Yes. Good point. It's obvious to a native speaker, but not obvious to someone learning English, which is the purpose of answering...

Answer (score 1):

**[Boss-Eyed](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boss-eyed)**

British slang term for being Cross-Eyed.

Comment: Never seen the term but on the page which you linked to it says `Boss-Eyed, said of a person with one eye, or rather with one eye injured, a person with an obliquity of vision.` Not exactly the same as being cross-eyed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The link certainly doesn't back up the claim, but the term is correct. The episode *Calendar Geeks* of the IT Crowd did a big thing on it. Here's a clip from YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHLbwwqCY9o

Comment: FWIW, I (English) have always used ‘cross-eyed’.  I've heard ‘boss-eyed’, but always assumed it was a mistake.

Comment: I grew up in the North of England. From an early age, I was diagnosed with strabismus. I got called "boss-eyed" on numerous occasions by my less charitable peers.

Comment: "Boss-eyed" is the immediate term which came to mind upon reading the question. I had no idea it was slang: I thought it was the international correct term. I never knew other people wouldn't understand it.

Comment: For me, it brings to mind Cockney rhyming slang,

Answer (score 0):

"crossing your eyes" sounds most fluent to me.

I've never heard "looking cross-eyed" before, but I can tell what it means.

"rolling your eyes" means to look upward, not toward the nose.

"squinting" just means closing your eyes a little bit while looking at something. It is body language that people make when trying to read something small.

Comment: Squinting is not mere "body language."  The squint actually helps you to see better - and, of course, it reduces the painfully bright glare of the sun on a hot, clear day.